# DesiredProperty change pending

Tags: azure-iot-hub

External source sends a desiredProperty change command with UpdateTwin.

There is already another change message for the same property from another source. This pending change has not reported yet from the device.

Does exist a way, the IoT Hub to block the new change command, till the first desiredProperty command is reported from the device?

Also in UpdateTwin, how the optional parameter ModuleId can be used?

EDIT: my syntax was not correct  in this sentence "till the first DesiredProperty command is reported from the device"  I meant, till the device would confirm the pending change of the desired property, via the ReportedProperties.

Answer (score 0):

The device twins represents a state between the two ends such as the cloud back-end and real device. These two ends are connected each other via device-facing and service-facing endpoints using a distributed disconnectable connections over the internet.

The device twins has a built-in generic support for synchronizing those two ends for finally state of the device twins such as desired (service-facing side) properties and reported (device-facing side) properties including their metadata and twin change notifications.

Based on the above device twins properties and their change notifications can be built any state machine between the back-end and device for running in the distributed disconnectable communication model.

Each side of the device twins has a responsibility to make a valid state transmission. In the case of invalid or in pending state, the request must be rejected with the status code until it is ready for next/new transmission.

I do recommend to read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-twin-how-to-configure) document where is described an implementation of the changing state on the device twins.

Comment: thank you @Roman Kiss, but I know about Device Twins. My question is about other issue, related with a nice to have feature, if possible.

Comment: @stefan2410, please use the following link for new features, feedbacks, ideas, etc. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot

Answer (score 0):

@Roman Kiss described Device Twins pretty well in his answer. I would still like to add to his response.
As you have certainly understood from Roman's answer and the documentation he points to, the nature of Device Twins is such that there is no out of the box way to cancel a device twin change request that would be pending.
It seems to me you are trying to queue state changes for the device, which Twins are not designed or meant for.
Also in your question "... *till the first desiredProperty command is reported from the device*...", this statement is incorrect as devices do not report desired properties, they receive them. They report Reported properties instead.
One way of implementing something close to what you are trying to achieve could be to have the device update its Twin with a Reported Property that would indicate it has switched to the state desired, and before setting a new state through a Desired Property you would check the latest reported property and it's update time to ensure it has indeed been received by the device.
You can also look at [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-jobs) as a way to manage tasks against IoT Hub.

About your question on the ModuleId parameter, this one is to be used when working with modules running on an Azure IoT Edge device. Each module of an IoT Edge device has it's own Module Twin which is addressed using the Device Id of the Edge device hosting the Module and the ModuleId.

Comment: I know about the Device Twins. I meant also the Reported Properties from the device. My question was if there is a built-in feature in Device Twins to relate a specific Reported Property version with its DesiredProperty change and if it could block the new change meanwhile. I know how to do it with a back-end solution, it would be nice if it was built-in n Device Twins.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TTL (TimeToLive) feature available for the Cloud2Device messages. That may be a workaround for the task. See [Message expiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d#message-expiration-time-to-live) doc.